# Infinite recursion in flush() method with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, junit

I this this is a weird problem but there it goes!

Putting in context:
I´m implementing my JUnit test and I´m testing a class called songJPA. I create a song (OK) , then I create a song with the same name and i expect a Exception (OK) and finally I would like to delete the first song create (Not to have an error in the next execution test time).

The problem is that when I execute the DeleteSongTest() individually, It Works and delete my song, but when I execute the all of them, It doesn´t work, It enter in a infinite recursion. I think it happends in the flush() method and I tried to debug but it´s impossible.

I paste all the classes wich I´m working.

The JUNIT TEST CLASS:

```
public class SongCRUDTest {

private SongJPA testSong1;
private SongJPA testSong2;
private SongJPAJpaController slc;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    testSong1= new SongJPA("TestTitle", 120, 19, new SongInfoJPA(), "TestArtist", Genre.CLASSICAL);
    testSong2= new SongJPA("TestTitle", 122, 12, new SongInfoJPA(), "TestArtist2", Genre.BLUES);
    slc =  new  SongJPAJpaController();
}

@Test
public void A_createSong(){
    slc.create(testSong1);
}


@Test(expected = PersistenceException.class)
public void B_createDuplicatedTestSong() {
    slc.create(testSong2);
}   

@Ignore
@Test
public  void C_deleteSong() throws NonexistentEntityException{
    SongJPA songToDelete= slc.findSongJPAByTitle("TestTitle");
    if(songToDelete!=null)
        slc.destroy(songToDelete.getId());
}
```

The destroy method that only works when I execute individually. (Is from a netbeans template)

```
 public void destroy(int id) throws NonexistentEntityException {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        SongJPA songJPA;
        try {
            songJPA = em.getReference(SongJPA.class, id);
            songJPA.getId();
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
            throw new NonexistentEntityException("The songJPA with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
        }
        em.remove(songJPA);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

EDITION1: create() method

`public void create(SongJPA songJPA) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(songJPA);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }`

[image]

Seconds later

> 54587 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 41000
>   54587 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try > restarting transaction

TIA for help!!!!

Comment: Can you show the `create()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Once you get an exception from a JPA method, you must consider that the transaction must be rolled back, and the EM must be closed: the first-level cache is in a bad state and can't be recovered. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-exceptions for details.

Use `EM.find` rather than `EM.getReference`, and test for null. `getReference` is used when you **know** an entity with the given ID exists. And it thus throws an exception if it appears later that it doesn't, but it's already too late. Whereas `find` executes a query to get the state of the entity, and returns null if it doesn't exist. You may create the entity if it doesn't exist yet, or delete it if it exists.

Moreover, it appears that you're expecting the tests to run in a fixed order. You shouldn't. Each unit test should run separately, and should run whether or not a previous test has already been run. Use a method annotated with `@After` to execute some cleanup after each test.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your reply @JB Nizet.

First issue, I tried with EM.find and It doesn´t work either, I added a System.out.println() just in the getId() method, and it returns me the correct ID. The problem cames later in flush() method.

About the second issue, I also tried by using the After and AfterClass annotations, but it´s the same.

I tried to execute the method in a fixed order becouse I tried to wait a little bit before executing the problematic method

I´m thinking in making different test classes, separate this method from others and then involve everything in a TestSuite.

Comment: Ok, Definitely, It´s the same if I separate methods in test classes and I run in a common Test Suite...Any more suggestions?